# Margin notes on the wrong page when using landscape in memoir

Tags: graphics, memoir, marginpar, landscape, marginnote

I have tried several similar to the following code, but the best that I can get is the `marginpar` on one side and the `figure` in the following.

The first `\marginpar{\lipsum[11]}\lipsum[1]` is positioned as expected while the second `\marginpar{\lipsum[11]}`, inside afterpage, does not.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{eucal}\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{latexsym}\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{lscape}%\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setstocksize{297mm}{210mm}
\settrimmedsize{297mm}{210mm}{*}
\settypeblocksize{252mm}{150mm}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{20mm}{40mm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{20mm}{25mm}{*}
\setheadfoot{10mm}{10mm}
\setmarginnotes{5mm}{30mm}{2\onelineskip}
\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\mainmatter

\chapter{Chapter}

\marginpar{\lipsum[11]}\lipsum[1]%% works correctly

\afterpage{%%
\marginpar{Again: \lipsum[11]}%% goes one page before the figure
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}
\centering\includegraphics[width=1.55\textwidth]{image.pdf}
\caption{Caption}\label{img01}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
}%%

\end{document}
```

What I would like to achieve is just a "simple" landscape page with one picture and a brief text comment in the fore margin. And then to write more such pages.

I have tried to manage the `marginpar` (or `marginnote`) in relation to afterpage/landscape in several ways now, is there a way to fix this syntax? Or a completely different approach would be better?

PS: sorry, since you need any image.pdf to make mine a MWE.

---

### Addendum:

Is this problem related to afterpage or landscape? Substituting `\afterpage{...}` with the following, I get always the same: note on the recto page and figure on the corresponding verso page.

```
\newpage%%\clearpage

%\afterpage{%%
%\begin{landscape}
\marginpar{Ancora: \lipsum[11]}
\begin{figure}
\centering\includegraphics[angle=90,width=\textwidth]{image.pdf}
\caption{Caption}\label{img01}
\end{figure}
%\end{landscape}
%}%%

\newpage%%\clearpage
```

What I obtain is always very similar to page 2 and 3 in the following image, while I would like contents of pages 2 and 3 to be on the same page.

This misbehaviour happens also with - e.g. - `width=.15\textwidth`: so I'm thinking it's not even a matter of "top of the marginnote aligned to the top of the figure". Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You are aware that landscape starts a new page? Have you tried adding it inside the landscape env?

Comment: Yes, of course, thanks....this was included in "I have tried several similar to the following"....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This compiles just fine

```
\begin{landscape}
\marginpar{Again: \lipsum[11]}%% goes one page before the figure
\begin{figure}
```

But of course

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}
\marginpar{Again: \lipsum[11]}%% goes one page before the figure
```

will not work as both `figure` and `\marginpar` are floats and they do not mix.

In the last example, `\sidebar` (similar to `\marginnote` from the package of the same name) will work.

---

From the comment below, by daleif:

If the margin comment has to be in the portrait margin, then you cannot use the `landscape` env. You need the `sideways` env (not the `sidewaysfigure`).

Comment: MMhh...No sidebar package in my package manager (MikTeX 2.9).Your first code compiles (no errors), but the positioning of the contents of \marginpar{} is not acceptable: part of it gets out of the page

Comment: Sidebar is a feature in memoir

Comment: No way, not even with sidebar. And the output is still very similar using appropriate packages and environment sidewaysfigure instead...

Comment: Then explain what exactly it is you need. If the margin comment has to be in the portrait margin, then you cannot use the `landscape` env. You need the `sideways` env (not the `sideways`figure`)

Comment: Man, you did it. This use of env sideways behaves as I expected. Thank you twice cause it's sunday.